# Can't get Django to import on python3

Tags: python, django, centos6

I am using CentOS and I installed django (pip install Django==1.7.1), however, it will not import with python3.

If I am in python 2.6.6 (CentOS default for python), then I can import it no problem, however, if I am in python 3.4 it says it doesn't exists. I know that I have to add it to the path by doing:

```
>> sys.path.append('/python_django_path')
```

but even this didn't work. Does anyone know how I get this to work for python3?

Comment: `pip3 install django==1.7.1`

Comment: how do I get pip3 on centos? sudo yum install pip3?

Comment: if you are using python3.4, it should be installed with python. if python3 is in your path, theres a 90% chance pip3 is as well. if its not, it should be in the `scripts` folder under where the python executable exists.

Comment: Sorry, apparently it was listed as pip3.4, not pip3. Thanks for your help! I would upvote your comment but I don't have a high enough rep